# jQuery list item based on value

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Please can someone tell me why this doesn't work. If i could have a jsfiddle example of it working it would be great.

Here is my jsfiddle for you to look at..
http://jsfiddle.net/kQXCM/3/

I just want the li(times) showing that matches the data

The ID clock is in the li
The result hold the time from the db e.g. 5.30PM
The logging through the console is detecting the correct evals.
 Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#datebooked', function(e) {
    jQuery(".times li[clock='5.00PM'],[clock='5.30PM'],[clock='6.00PM'],[clock='6.30PM'],[clock='7.00PM'],[clock='7.30PM'],[clock='8.00PM'],[clock='9.30PM'],[clock='9.00PM'],[clock='8.00PM'],[clock='8.30PM']").show();

    //Selects the date id
    var id = jQuery(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    //Store it in result
    result = data[++id].time;


    jQuery(".times li").each(function(idx, li) {

        jQuery.each(result, function(val, i) {

            var product = jQuery(li).attr("clock");
            if (i == product) {
                jQuery(".times li[clock='" + product + "']").show();
                console.log("EQUAL" + i + " = " + product);
            } else {
                jQuery(".times li[clock='" + product + "']").hide();
                console.log("NOT EQUAL");
            }
        });
    });
    //END list item loop
});
```

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle example of what is not working, that would be helpful.   What is the expected result here?   What is not working?

Comment: Hi Charlie. Just done it.

Comment: thanks, but what is the expected result?   When I use your fiddle, I see a page with lots of times.   Once I pick something from the dropdown list, there is only one time in the list.   Is that what you want?

Comment: No, in the data there are 3 times. I want the times in the data to show. Does that make sense? Thank you for your time on this.